# Form Submission in Django without Page Refresh using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm a newbie in python so this might be fixed easily.

I'm trying to do a register form using Jquery with Django.
I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgnPSmrQrXI&t=119s)

when I click on the button it shows me the success message in the alert but nothing is inserted in the database.

Here is my code :

> register.html

```
<body>
<form id="add_user_form">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {# label et input du uti_login de la class Form#}
    <label for="UTI_LOGIN">Insérer un surnom d'utilisateur</label>
    <input id="UTI_LOGIN" type="text" name="UTI_LOGIN">
    <br>
        {# label et input du UTI_NOM de la class LoginForm#}
    <label for="UTI_NOM">Insérer un nom d'utilisateur</label>
    <input id="UTI_NOM" type="text" name="UTI_NOM">
    <br>
        {# label et input du UTI_PRENOM de la class LoginForm#}
    <label for="UTI_PRENOM">Insérer un prenom d'utilisateur</label>
    <input id="UTI_PRENOM" type="text" name="UTI_PRENOM">
    <br>
        {# label et input du UTI_CIVILITE de la class LoginForm#}
    <label for="UTI_CIVILITE">Insérer un civilite d'utilisateur</label>
    <input id="UTI_CIVILITE" type="text" name="UTI_CIVILITE">
    <br>
        {# label et input du UTI_EMAIL de la class LoginForm#}
    <label for="UTI_EMAIL">Insérer un email d'utilisateur</label>
    <input id="UTI_EMAIL" type="text" name="UTI_EMAIL">
    <br>
    {# label et input du uti_mdp de la class LoginForm#}
    <label for="UTI_MDP">Insérer mot de passe</label>
    <input id="UTI_MDP" type="password" name="UTI_MDP">
    <br>

    <label for="UTI_SUPPRIME">Hidden label checked</label>
    <input id="UTI_SUPPRIME" type="checkbox" hidden checked>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input value="S'inscrire ! ☺" type="submit">
</form>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('submit','#add_user_form',function (e) {
{#                    prevent the page getting refreshed#}
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'registerSearch',
                data:{
                    username:$('#UTI_LOGIN').val(),
                    mdp:$('#UTI_MDP').val(),
                    nom:$('#UTI_NOM').val(),
                    prenom:$('#UTI_PRENOM').val(),
                    civilite:$('#UTI_CIVILITE').val(),
                    email:$('#UTI_EMAIL').val(),
                    supp:$('#UTI_SUPPRIME').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name = csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success:function () {
                    alert("Utilisateur crée !");
                }

            })
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'register', views.register_list, name='register'),
    url(r'registerSearch', views.registersearch_list),
]
```

> views.py

```
def register_list(request):
    return render(request, 'esigapp/register.html', {})


def registersearch_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        mdp = request.POST['mdp']
        nom = request.POST['nom']
        prenom = request.POST['prenom']
        civil = request.POST['civilite']
        email = request.POST['email']
        supp = request.POST['supp']

        Sie_utilisateur.objects.create(
            UTI_LOGIN=username,
            UTI_MDP=mdp,
            UTI_NOM=nom,
            UTI_PRENOM=prenom,
            UTI_CIVILITE=civil,
            UTI_EMAIL=email,
            UTI_SUPPRIME=supp
        )
    return HttpResponse('')
```

and finally

> models.py

```
class Sie_utilisateur(models.Model):
    UTI_LOGIN = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    UTI_MDP = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    UTI_NOM = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    UTI_PRENOM = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    UTI_CIVILITE = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    UTI_EMAIL = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    UTI_SUPPRIME = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.UTI_NOM
```

Some tips are also useful :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not Ajax. It's simply that you didn't anchor or terminate your URL patterns; so the URL "/registerSearch" matches the first one, "register".

Make sure you use beginning and end anchors:

```
url(r'^register$', views.register_list, name='register'),
url(r'^registerSearch$', views.registersearch_list),
```

You should probably also return something explicit in your registerSearch view so that your Ajax knows that the item has actually been created.

Comment: If I write this the page doesn't load because of the '/' should I do like :
`url(r'^register/$', views.register_list, name='register'),
url(r'^registerSearch/$', views.registersearch_list),`

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Make sure you change your Ajax function to post to "/registerSearch/" as well.

Comment: So I've corrected like this : 
    `url(r'^register/$', views.register_list, name='register'),
    url(r'^registerSearch/$', views.registersearch_list),`
Now it shows me an error in the console :
`POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/registerSearch net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: And if I do this : 
   `url(r'^register/$', views.register_list, name='register'),
    url(r'^register/registerSearch$', views.registersearch_list),`

It shows me this :

`POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/registerSearch 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: You didn't follow the second part of my comment: make sure you change the place your ajax function is posting to, it needs slashes both before and after.

Comment: Now my code is like this : In the $.ajax
`url: '/registerSearch/',` And in the urls.py :  `url(r'^register/$', views.register_list, name='register'),
    url(r'^registerSearch$', views.registersearch_list),`